# Determine if an HTML tag name is valid

Tags: javascript, html, eslint

We've developed an [ESLint rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/valid-by-tagname.md) to determine if a tag name used inside the Protractor's `by.tagName()` locator is valid.

> A Tag Name is considered valid when:
>
> - It can contain alphanumeric characters.
> - It can contain the dash(-) symbol.
> - It cannot start with dash or a number.
> - It cannot end with dash.

The Code:

```
'use strict'

var isTagName = /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*$/

module.exports = {
  meta: {
    schema: []
  },

  create: function (context) {
    return {
      'CallExpression': function (node) {
        var object = node.callee.object
        var property = node.callee.property

        var insideByTagName = object && property && object.name === 'by' && property.name === 'tagName'
        var argumentExists = node.arguments && node.arguments.length && node.arguments[0].value

        if (insideByTagName && argumentExists) {
          var tagName = node.arguments[0].value
          if (!tagName.match(isTagName) || tagName.endsWith('-')) {
            context.report({
              node: node,
              message: 'Invalid TagName value: "' + tagName + '"'
            })
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to decrease nested-ness and improve on readability?

FYI, using [`standard` JS code style](https://standardjs.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code is fine IMO, but *technically* it's possible to flatten using a complete regexp

```
var isTagName = /^[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$/
```

plus dubious/stinky value fallbacks and ES2015 arrow function:

```
  create: context => ({
    CallExpression: node => {
      if ((node.callee.object || {}).name !== 'by' ||
          (node.callee.property || {}).name !== 'tagName') {
        return
      }
      var tagName = ((node.arguments || [])[0] || {}).value
      if (tagName && !tagName.match(isTagName)) {
        context.report({
          node,
          message: `Invalid tag name: "${tagName}"`
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: You can use shorter regex [`/^[a-z](-?[a-z0-9]+)*$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/XIriSr/1)

Comment: And use `RegExp#test` instead of `String#match` to check if the string contains the pattern. `match` is used for data extraction.